# Print values and it's associated index when working with vectors / matrix in J

Tags: search, indexing, j

If I want to check how many values in a vector or matrix are less than a given value
I can use +/ (a < 20). But what if I wanted to know both the specific value and it's index.
Something like (2(value) 5(index)) as a table. I looked at i., i: (which give first and last position) and I. Does sorting first help?

Comment: It’s be easier if you gave examples, but in short, yes, `I.` (capital) is what you want to get the indices. Then you’d pull out the values at those indices and stitch them together to get your table of (index, value) pairs. Or you can be cute and do `20 $.@:< a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very common pattern in J is the creation of a mask from a filter and applying an action on and/or using the masked data in a hook or fork:

```
((actions) (filter)) (data)
```

For example:

```
NB. Random array
a =: ? 20 $ 10
6 3 9 0 3 3 0 6 2 9 2 4 6 8 7 4 6 1 7 1

NB. Filter and mask
f =: 5 < ]
m =: f a
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0

NB. Values of a on m
m # a
6 9 6 9 6 8 7 6 7

NB. Indices of a on m
I. m
0 2 7 9 12 13 14 16 18

NB. Joint results
(I.m) ,: (m # a)
0 2 7 9 12 13 14 16 18
6 9 6 9  6  8  7  6  7
```

In other words, in this case you have `m&#` and `f` acting on `a` and `I.` acting on `m`. Notice that the final result can be derived from an action on `m` alone by commuting the arguments of copy `#~`:

```
(I. ,: (a #~ ]) m
0 2 7 9 12 13 14 16 18
6 9 6 9  6  8  7  6  7
```

and `a` can be pulled out from the action on `m` like so:

```
a ( (]I.) ,: (#~ ])) m
```

But since `m` itself is derived from an action (`f`) on `a`, we can write:

```
a ( (]I.) ,: (#~ ])) (f a)
```

which is a simple monadic hook `y v (f y)` → `(v f) y`.

Therefore:

```
action =: (]I.) ,: (#~ ])
filter =: 5 < ]
data =: a

(action filter) data
0 2 7 9 12 13 14 16 18
6 9 6 9  6  8  7  6  7
```

Comment: So you should specify verbs and then apply them to your data.